# In GridView after filtering the list, the index changes and the context of item is wrong

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am having a `GridList View` in which I am passing data from firebase. When I click on the items it works fine without filtering but when I filter it with searchView then it does not update the index of the list and then provides a different item's context.

I do not know how to update the item while filtering.

**Homepage.Activity**

```
package com.project.quizapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import static com.project.quizapp.LogIn.catList;
import static com.project.quizapp.LogIn.selected_cat_index_app;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.project.quizapp.CatGridAdapter;

public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

CatGridAdapter adapter;
private GridView catGrid;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebasefirestore;
    public static List<CategoryModelClass> resultData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        //Binding view and adding toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Subjects");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this, dashActivity.class));

            }
        });
        //Adapter to set all the views
        catGrid = findViewById(R.id.catGridview);
        adapter = new CatGridAdapter(catList);
        catGrid.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


    //Filtering all tthe views
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Inflating all the views and filtering
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        MenuItem menuitem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchMenu);
        SearchView searchview = (SearchView) menuitem.getActionView();
        searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Calling filters on the search attempt
                //adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                resultData = new ArrayList<>();
                for(CategoryModelClass categoryModelClass:catList){
                    if(categoryModelClass.getName().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())){
                        resultData.add(categoryModelClass);
                    }

                    adapter = new CatGridAdapter(resultData);

                    catGrid.setAdapter(adapter);



                }

                return true;
            }
        });
        return true;

    }

    //Adding search icon to the toolbar
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.searchMenu){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**CatGridAdapter.java**

```
package com.project.quizapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import static com.project.quizapp.LogIn.selected_cat_index_app;
import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;

//Creating the adapter wih the default BaseAdapter
//Also implementing

public class CatGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    //List of all the class variables
    private List<CategoryModelClass> catList;

    //Initializing the list wih constructor
    public CatGridAdapter(List<CategoryModelClass> catList) {
        this.catList = catList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return catList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view;

        if(convertView == null){
            //Adding all the views as we get the data from firebase
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cat_item_layout,parent,false);
        }
        else{
            view = convertView;
        }



        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //selected_cat_index_app = position;
            //   Toast.makeText(parent.getChildAt(position), catList.get(position).getName()+" "+String.valueOf(catList.indexOf(position)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), SetsActivity.class);
                parent.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.catName)).setText(catList.get(position).getName());


        Random rnd = new Random();
        int color = Color.argb(255,rnd.nextInt(255),rnd.nextInt(255),rnd.nextInt(255));
        view.setBackgroundColor(color);
        return view;
    }

}
```

**CategoryModelClass.java**

```
package com.project.quizapp;

//Model class to fetch the quiz subjects from the Cloud Firestone
public class CategoryModelClass {
    //private variable for ID and the name of
    private String id;
    private String name;

    //constructor
    public CategoryModelClass(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    //methods
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are filtering the list, use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` instead of `GridView`.

Comment: Tried and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Either implement a `Filterable` interface in the adapter or update your `onQueryTextChange` implementation.

Whenever you are typing, every time you are creating a new adapter with filtered data.

try this.. create new method in adapter

```
public void updateData(List<CategoryModelClass> catList){
        this.catList = catList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and call from `onQueryTextChange`

```
 @Override
 public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                resultData = new ArrayList<>();
                for (CategoryModelClass categoryModelClass : catList) {
                    if (categoryModelClass.getName().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())) {
                        resultData.add(categoryModelClass);
                    }
                    adapter.updateData(resultData);
                }
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It is the same as before.